# How to set constant text style definitions

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind and currently making my first app, I already figured out the different text styles that I wanna use for example:

Primary: bold, 1.5rem
Secondary: bold, 1rem

etc...

Wanted to know how can I use the tailwind.config to define these characteristics of the text so I don't have to always be using className: 'font-bold text-2xl' and I can do something like 'textstyle-primary' instead.

Appreciate the help before hand :3

I used the tailwind.config like this:
 `theme: { container: { center: true, padding: "2rem", screens: { "2xl": "1400px", }, }, extend: { textStyles: { 'logo': { 'font-size': '1.5rem', 'font-weight': 'bold', }, },`

But when I go to my page to use the textstyle, it won't apply the font attributes I'm looking for